# Setting DevExpress ASPxCheckBox CheckState via Eval

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, eval

In ASP.Net 4.0, I'm trying to utilise the DevExpress ASPxCheckBox's ability to have "three states": checked, unchecked and indeterminate. I'd like to set this based on the value of a boolean: "Checked" when the boolean is true, "Unchecked" when false, and "Indeterminate" when null. To this end, I'm trying to use the following code in my page:

```
 <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cb_located" runat="server" AllowGrayed="true"  AllowGrayedByClick="true" CheckState='<%# Eval("located") == DBNull.Value ? "Indeterminate" : (bool)Eval("PropertyLocated") == true ? "Checked" : "Unchecked" %>' />
```

However, this gives me the error

> CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to
>   'DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CheckState'

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CheckState enumeration](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesCheckStateEnumtopic). So instead of string value `"Indeterminate"` use `CheckState.Indeterminate` etc.

Comment: I swear I'd tried that already. Works perfectly now using `CheckState='<%# Eval("located") == null ? CheckState.Indeterminate : (bool)Eval("located") == true ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked %>' `. Thank you very much!